# GWT download file thru RemoteServiceServlet

Tags: gwt

I have a button called export when clicked it has to export the available records in a grid into a csv file. I was able to achieve this by regular servlet but with a class extending RemoteServiceServlet.. Even if I get the response and set the bytes on it as outputstream it does not work..Andy suggestions are appreciated

I tried creating an Anchor and that anchor sends the request to a regular servlet I can acheive it but i need to maintain some objects fetched from the client...I don't just want to send String params

Window.Location.assign("http://localhost:8080/Commenting/DownloadController?filters="+stringBuffer.toString());

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) to send/[retrieve data from HTTP server](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/package-summary.html).